# Setting Firefox hot keys to be like in Windows 

Tags: windows, firefox

I have been using Firefox for years on Windows and I do a lot with keyboard. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> shows the downloads. And now on Ubuntu all this is broken. I need an easy way to set Windows-Firefox keyboard shortcuts for Ubuntu-Firefox.

Comment: I hate it when it comes to this silly fight about shortcuts on the SAME application.
Microsoft translates shortcuts (e.g. bold = ctrl + b in italian is grassetto = ctrl + g): that's just crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **KeyConfig extension**. it seems to be the least painful way to assign shortcut keys.

See this page: [Change Firefox Keyboard Shortcuts](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2009/08/15/change-firefox-keyboard-shortcuts-add-on-extension/)

[image: KeyConfig assignments dialog]

Although it does not contain preconfigured bindings for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the KeyConfig extension, there is an extension that *is* available on the Ubuntu extensions website and needs no Firefox restart: [Customizable Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/). It adds a shortcuts-tab in the preferences dialog and presents shortcuts grouped on theme.
Check the Mozilla Support support website for the [shortcuts as used on Windows](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#os=win).

[image: Customizable Shortcuts screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) plugin. You can install it [here.](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi)

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up the dialog and set new keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score -1):

First of all the shortcuts for firefox in ubuntu an d windows are a lot different (***example for downloads in ubuntu the shortcut is ctrl+shift+y**)
you should refer for documentation in ubuntu firefox help menu or use internet resources

Comment: I need a quick way to make keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu-Firefox to be the same as in Windows-Firefox. If I was unclear in my post, please correct me

Comment: visit this link it may help http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts?s=customize+shortcut&r=0&as=s(I was not able to find how to make custom shortcut)